# executebatch() in JDBC inserts only few records

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm facing an issue with batches in JDBC, I add a prepared statement to a batch, but when I execute the batch, only few records are inserted, I searched and I didn't figured it out, here is the code:
I'm into a resultset of another prepared statement, is it a problem? Thank you!

```
 //autocommitFALSE (...)
 while(rs.next()){ 



            int idrobot = rs.getInt("idRobot");  
            if (idrobot != idrn) {
                  String fullstatenew2 = "INSERT INTO `fullstate`(`idR`, `idC`, `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`, `s5`, `s6`, `s7`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                  java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStmt9 = conn.prepareStatement(fullstatenew2);

                    preparedStmt9.setInt(1, robot);
                    preparedStmt9.setString(2, cluster);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(3, s1);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(4, s2);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(5, s3);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(6, s4);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(7, s5);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(8, s6);
                    preparedStmt9.setInt(9, s7);

                    preparedStmt9.addBatch();

                    if(i>10000) //it's really not like this, but this is the sense {
                        preparedStmt9.executeBatch();
                        System.out.println("insert");
                    }
                    conn.commit();
```

Comment: add batch should be in a loop and execute batch should be after the loop. also I don't see you increment the i here.

Comment: Yes, I don't increment the I because i don't really make this check, ok thankks, I'll try.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. It seemed a dumb question, but I was not capable to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add batch should be in a loop and execute batch should be after the loop.